# Can a comma always replace a colon?

Tags: meaning, punctuation

Can a comma always replace a colon? I am not sure, but I think I've heard you can replace a colon (:) with a comma (,) without significantly changing the meaning in any way, the comma is a more general punctuation so the meaning becomes a little more blurred. Is that the case in every case?

For example:

> You had two choices: yes or no.
>
> You had two choices, yes or no.

Comment: The answer will rarely be “yes" when you include words like _always_ and _every_ in your question. Maybe I’m stating the obvious, but you can’t replace these colons with commas: _He wanted to read Proverbs 11:28 at the 10:30 service._

Comment: What about the above examples? I should have said in most standard cases.

Comment: It’s never too late to edit your question.

Comment: @J.R. So there will *always* be times when we should say *never,* but it's not right to say that we should *never* say *always*? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma and semicolon are both used to show or create pause points in sentences.

Therefore, they can often be interchangeable and still conform to what is generally considered acceptable.

However, the meaning will generally be changed, even if it is a subtle change. In general, semicolons create a stronger pause.

If two parts of a sentence are independent, it is often more conventional to join them with a semicolon, if we want to join them:

> She hesitated to tell him the bad news; he was going to be devastated.

In that example, a writer may want to join the two parts of the sentence because they are so closely related, or because a writer wants to create or emphasize a close relationship. The semicolon can do that, but a comma would create confusion, or be considered a comma splice error.

Commas are also used to join independent clauses, but this works better for some sentences than for others.

We acceptably use commas especially when both clauses are short, and/or when both clauses are concordant in some way:

> I entered, she left.

Three clauses:

> I came, I saw, I conquered.

In many cases, joining independent clauses doesn't work so well, and may be considered unacceptable. Your sentence, for example, links a complex sentence with an independent clause with a comma (between *any way* and *the comma*) that most people, I believe, would say is incorrect or nonstandard.

In some of my sentences, above, we couldn't felicitously replace some of the commas with semicolons:

> *Therefore; they can often be interchangeable and still conform to what is generally considered acceptable.

There's no reason to use the strong pause indicator after *therefore* in that sentence. Doing so would generally be seen as odd at best, and more likely as "incorrect" or nonstandard in most contexts.

Also, we can't replace semicolons with commas in cases where multiple pause markers are used and we need the semicolon's strength to mark boundaries between elements:

> He inherited a lot of money from his parents when he was young; consequently, he never had to work.
>
> She loved baked goods, like cakes, breads, and bagels; fried things, like fish and chips; jams, jellies, and preserves; and pasta.

In the above, the semicolon is needed to create such separations or groupings.

Comment: "The comma and semicolon are both used to show or create pause points in sentences. " Not so, both have specific grammatical and syntactic uses, having little to do with where a speaker might pause., mush less the strength of a pause. This is a common misunderstanding.

Comment: English isn't JavaScript. "The main task of the semicolon is to mark a break that is stronger than a comma but not as final as a full stop." Oxford Dictionaries. Or maybe you'd like to list or point us to these "specific and syntactic" uses? And operationally define *grammar*?

Comment: I describe several of the functions of a colon in my answer. I don't describe uses of a semi colon, since the question didn't ask about the semi-colon and it is thus not relevant. "break point" as used in that quote is, I believe, a conceptual break, while 'pause point" refers to a verbal, spoken pause. The two are not the same. As for an operational definition of "grammar" this whole site serves as one.  Downvote stands

Answer (score 2):

A colon can sever several functions. Most of these cannot correctly be done using a comma instead.

- A colon can introduce a list.

  > > There are four chores I want you to do: make the bed, do the dishes, mow the lawn, and dust the mantel.

  If the list is only two items long, a comma might be used instead, but a colon is clearer and better; there is no advantage to using a comma instead. (This is the case in the examples in the question.)
- A colon can be used to introduce a quotation.

  > > Martin Luther Kink Jr famously said: "I have a dream that one day my children will be judged by the content of their character, not the color of their skin
- A Colon is used to separate a title from a sub-title.

  > > *The Hunting of the Snark: An Agony in Eight Fits*
- A colon can precede a description or elaboration:

  > > The character of Miles is presented as damaged but not dysfunctional: He is often manic, but generally in the service of rational goals

  In this use a comma or semi-colon may work (depending on whether the parts are independent clauses or not) but the colon emphasizes that the second part describes or expands on or provides evidence for the first.
- A colon can introduce a definition

  > > "egregious": outstandingly bad or shocking.

  Here a comma would not work, although a dash could.
- A colon can be used to introduce a logical conclusion, or an effect of the previous statement.

  > > - There was only one possible explanation: the train had never arrived.
  > >       Jane was now sure of one thing: Colin did not love her.
- One may use a colon after the salutation in a formal letter.

  > > Dear Ms. Smith:
- A colon is used to show time in hours an minutes, or hours, minutes and seconds.

  > > - 9:15 pm
  > > - 14:34:18 UTC
- A colon is used between chapter and verse in citations from the Bible or other works with a similar convention.

  > > John 2:15

The phrases before and after a colon may be independent clauses which could be written as complete sentences, but they need not be so.

Comment: Strangely enough, in dictionaries, where a colon introduces a definition, that is the one place where I've seen a blank space precede the colon. (See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence), for example.)